# Angular errors in code on Expense.guard.ts component

Tags: angular

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, CanActivate, RouterStateSnapshot, Router, UrlTree } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ExpenseGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {}

  canActivate(
  next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean | UrlTree {
     let url: string = state.url;

         return this.checkLogin(url);
     }

     checkLogin(url: string): true | UrlTree {
        console.log("Url: " + url)
        let val: string = localStorage.getItem('isUserLoggedIn');

        if(val != null && val == "true"){
           if(url == "/login")
              this.router.parseUrl('/expense');
           else 
              return true;
        } else {
           return this.router.parseUrl('/login');
        }
     }
    }
```

The first error is on line 22,

> Function lacks ending return statement and return type does not include 'undefined'.

The second is on line 24

> Type 'string | null' is not assignable to type 'string'.
> Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'.

Answer (score 0):

```js
  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean | UrlTree {
      return this.checkLogin(state.url);
  }

  checkLogin(url: string): true | UrlTree {
    console.log("Url: " + url)
    const val: string = localStorage.getItem('isUserLoggedIn');

     if (val === 'true' && url === '/login') {
        this.router.parseUrl('/expense');
        return true;
     }

     this.router.parseUrl('/login');
     return false;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Type 'string | null' is not assignable to type 'string'. Type 'null'
> is not assignable to type 'string'.

In the below code, the variable `val` type is mentioned as `string`.

```
let val: string = localStorage.getItem('isUserLoggedIn');
```

However, the `Storage.getItem` can either return `string` if the key is found or `null` if not found [[Storage.getItem]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem).

[image]

Since, on the next line you are checking the existence of value in `val` variable, there is no need to add the type to the `val`.

> Function lacks ending return statement and return type does not
> include 'undefined'.

The function `checkLogin` either returns boolean value `true` or `UrlTree`. The check login function doesn't return anything when `val` is truthy and url is `login`.

```
if (val != null && val == "true") {
  if (url == "/login")
    this.router.parseUrl('/expense'); <---- doesn't return anything
  else
    return true;
```

Instead of doing `val != null && val == "true"` you can check truthiness of `val` using `if (val)`  condition

```
checkLogin(url: string): true | UrlTree {
  console.log("Url: " + url)
  const val = localStorage.getItem('isUserLoggedIn');

  if( val ) {
    return url === '/login' ? this.router.parseUrl('/expense'): true;
  } else {
    return this.router.parseUrl('/login');
  }
}
```